# I got two questions about the Starman Tesla roadster orbiting the solar system

Tags: spacex, tesla-roadster

First, is it possible that the Starman Tesla roadster re-enters the earths orbit as it's close to the earth?

Secondly, it's similar to the first one, is it possible that in 2020 when the Starman Tesla roadster passes near Mars, it enters Mars orbit?

Comment: Further related question/answer: [Starman trajectory in future](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/starman-trajectory-in-future/25400#25400)

Comment: And another one: [Will the Tesla Roadster/Falcon 9H 2nd stage ever be a navigation hazard to cis-lunar space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25054/will-the-tesla-roadster-falcon-9h-2nd-stage-ever-be-a-navigation-hazard-to-cis-l)

Comment: The roadster is in solar orbit now. To enter an orbit around Earth or Mars, an orbit insertion maneuver is necessary to slow down to a planet orbital velocity. Without fuel, an engine ignitable in zero gravity and an attitude control system this is not possible.