# Tesla Roadster new orbital elements

Tags: tesla-roadster

Has a TLE been posted somewhere for the Tesla Roadster in its new orbit out past Mars? I was hoping to paste it into SN7. Thanks

Comment: [SN7](https://www.streetcheck.co.uk/postcode/startingwith/sn7) is in the UK, i will be hard to paste orbital elements there. Or is SN7 something different? If so, can you add a link? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has a TLE ever been issued for a spacecraft trajectory not bound to Earth orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24314/has-a-tle-ever-been-issued-for-a-spacecraft-trajectory-not-bound-to-earth-orbit)

Comment: The only ambiguity in closing this question is to decide if [No, TLEs not issued for spacecraft not bound to Earth](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24317/12102) or perhaps [Horizons can be used to find Roadster's orbital elements](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25121/12102), or some other answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's a good question, but it would be better to look at all of the other answers here first. Currently we have 49 questions with the [Roadster tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tesla-roadster) already!

Comment: Pardon the novice question, but what do the acronyms TLE and SN7 mean?

Comment: @DanSorensen if you click on my link that includes "TLE" in the title and then follow the question-trail back, you'll find out what a TLE is, or check this site's tag for [`two-line-elements`](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-line-elements), but Wikipedia explains [Two Line Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) nicely. However for SN7 I've already posted a comment suggesting that it be explained further.

Comment: Does SN7 relate to the .sn7 disk snapshot file format? https://datatypes.net/open-sn7-files

Comment: Sorry SN7 as I used it is for the program Starry Night Pro version 7. I was hoping to use it to plot the orbit of the Tesla Roadster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're available on JPL Horizons. Here is a simulation of the Tesla's orbit I made using Horizons data, described further [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25028/12102):

http://orbitsimulator.com/gravitySimulatorCloud/simulations/1518192530417_teslaRoadsterFeb9Horizons.html

If you want the orbital elements or state vectors at any point in time, make sure the simulation is paused, then menu Objects > Edit Orbital Elements or Edit State Vectors will show them to you.

Answer (score 1):

TLEs are only for Earth orbiting objects. The best source of raw data is [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi). I don't know how you might put that in to SN7, but...

Comment: `-1` It might be better to point to where these have been already answered in much greater detail than to post a terse re-answer. The site is better when we work hard to point to the best answers. I know you've been extremely busy with this site for the last week, maybe better to let someone else with more time answer than to answer quickly? I've added a close vote and comment above.