# What is Elon Musk's Roadster orbital period?

Tags: spacex, orbit, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

On February 6th, 2018, SpaceX launched Elon Musk's Tesla Roadster to an elliptical heliocentric orbit as a dummy payload of the initial flight test of the new Falcon Heavy rocket.

**What is the orbital period of Elon's Roadster ?**
In other words, how long will it take to come back as close to the earth's orbit as it was at the end of the final burn ?

For reference, the car reached the following orbit:
[image] 
*Credit to Elon Musk: https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/961083704230674438*

Mandatory eye-candy:
[image]
*Screenshot taken from SpaceX livestream ["Live Views from Starman"](https://youtu.be/aBr2kKAHN6M)*

Comment: The period based on Musk's tweet and the periapsis and apoapsis shown there is about 900 days as calculated in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24981/12102) as well as Scott Manley in the linked video there. However, [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24973/current-speed-of-tesla-roadster-which-is-moving-to-asteriod-belt/24981#comment72489_24973) suggests those might not be correct. Let's wait a bit to see how this develops.

Comment: Using the JPL Horizons projected orbit, [I get 558 days](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25082/12102).