# What was the source of uncertainty on the Starman ejection burn?

Tags: spacex, propulsion, mission-design, tesla-roadster

> After the launch and six-hour cruise, the Falcon Heavy’s upper stage will fire a third time to send the Tesla into a cycling orbit between Earth and Mars. This should take the Tesla out as far as the Martian orbit around the Sun, or even a bit further. Musk said the vehicle should get as far as 380 to 450 million km from Earth, depending on how the third burn goes.
>   ( [source](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/02/at-the-pad-elon-musk-sizes-up-the-falcon-heavys-chance-of-success/) )

80 million kilometers is a huge tolerance. Normally rockets make very precise burns to arrive at specific trajectories and how the amount of fuel carried converts to delta-V and possible trajectory is well known.

What is the cause why the planned trajectory was defined with such poor precision? While I understand they are not aiming at any specific target, they should still know how much delta-V the rocket carries and how far it will get it.

Like, I'm happy your rocket can reach anywhere between Mars and the Asteroid Belt, but I'd be more confident if the word *"anywhere"* wasn't applied in so literal meaning...

Comment: [Is it Starman or is it the **Roadster**?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/946/12102)

Comment: They were doing a test to see what would happen to the third stage of the rocket after spending 6 hours in the Van Allen belt, being unsure what amount of boil-off or what effect it would have on the booster left the uncertainty.

Comment: I think it is uncertainty in the *maximum possible trajectory,* but not necessarily uncertainty in a given, targeted trajectory if they choose to do so. In other words, if they burn until they need to shut down to avoid explosion, they are not sure exactly when it runs out of gas. But that doesn't mean that that would be the uncertainty in a specific orbit as long as SECO3 happens before it runs out of gas. Considering the current [projections are for it to pass within 7 million km of Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25079/12102) and I don't think that's an accident.

Comment: A small uncertainty here makes a big difference way out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The source was that no-one cared; it was a test flight

Elon Musk's stated minimum goal of this flight was: [to not blow up Pad 39A](http://money.cnn.com/2018/02/04/technology/future/spacex-falcon-heavy-failure/index.html).<sub>(*)</sub>

> "I hope it makes it far enough away from the [launch] pad so that it does not cause pad damage," Musk said last year. "I would consider even that a win to be honest."

This was a test to see if the thing flies and makes it to orbit. To achieve high precision of the orbit was not on the agenda. They simply did not care about that, because already getting to orbit — any orbit — was a smashing success all on its own.

<sub>(*) The reason for this is that being allowed to use Pad 39A is pretty much like borrowing your grandparents' priceless crystal glasses for your private party: you do want to hand that back in pristine order. Oh, and because SpaceX **needs** the pad to do business. If it is broken, they cannot use it for launches that earn them money.</sub>

Comment: I think they probably care a great deal, Musk has a long history of understatement and managing expectation.

Comment: @GdD Musk was very clear about the expectations in the time leading up to the launch. He clearly stated that anything that is not an explosion on the launch pad is a success. Like he said in the press conference after the launch: his nightmare scenario would have been a wheel coming bouncing down the access way; a Tesla logo landing with a **THUD** in front of a camera. Anything that was not that, and he was happy.

Comment: Comment to down-voters: 1) explain why you down-vote. 2) If you think you can do better, by all means: author an answer.

Comment: That no-one cared was the reason for the unimportance of the exact orbit, but is no explanation for why it couldn't be predicted with higher accuracy. SpaceX has expert mission planners, tons of simulation tools and much experience with precise orbit insertions, few-seconds launch windows etc. It all doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: @derwodamaso And? Is your inability to wrap your mind around a situation an argument for something other than just that? Considering they were 5 **years** behind the originally promised delivery date — and despite reassurances that anything better than setting the historical launch pad on fire was a win they were very worried about that particular eventuality — it is safe to assume everyone at SpaceX had their hands full checking, double-checking and doing that all over a few times more to make sure SpaceX was not left with the world's most high tech, expensive and irreplaceable bonfire.

Comment: @MichaelK Someone passive-aggressive? :-P To make it clear: **not caring about something means it is irrelevant, not uncertain**. The "doesn't make sense" part was supposed to support the question.

Comment: @derwodamaso No not aggressive at all. **You** said that you cannot make sense of a situation that actually, demonstrably have happened, and put that forth as an argument. I simply asked: is that an argument for anything?