# Why doesn't SpaceX know how long orbital maneuver burns will take?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, dragon-v2

While listening in on today's Crew Dragon 1 rendezvous, I noticed something interesting: the announced duration for the final coelliptic burn was "25 to 35 seconds".  And this wasn't just a vague statement by PR: it was the actual transmission from mission control to the capsule.

Back in the Apollo days, NASA was able to give crews burn times to within a second (or less, for some of the brief midcourse corrections).  Why isn't SpaceX being this precise?

Comment: Why isn't SpaceX being this precise... in their *announced verbal descriptions of the durations* of brief midcourse corrections?

Comment: Well, how long between this communication and the scheduled start of burn?  If it is more than a couple orbits, then perhaps they haven't run the final calculation yet.  And weren't the Apollo burns controlled by the crew, whereas SpaceX burns are ground-controlled?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Most Apollo burns were done by computer; the manual maneuvers are few enough to be detailed [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40195/26446).

Comment: Having a deja vu https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25086/21562

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut  not really -- that was a rather different set of circumstances

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think the comment refers to what happens to the question and its answer, rather than what happens in space.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, this was the final transmission prior to the burn.  IIRC, it was about 20 minutes before, where the Apollo transmissions I've looked at were between one and two hours earlier.

Comment: That's consistent with Musk's companies ability to provide accurate time estimates, no surprise here. :-D